# Need a DAX expression to calculate Rate of Success

Tags: powerbi, dax, rate

I have a table called `Payment_Methods` in PBI with the following columns:

timestamp, weekDay, Hour, eventType, SuccessEvents, FailedEvents, addPymntCardInstance.

weekDay is ['Sunday', 'Monday', ..., 'Friday', 'Saturday']

Hour is [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 21, 22, 23]

I want to create a `PymntSuccessRate` using the DAX expression below, but the results are always the same all the way down across the column `PymntSuccessRate`. How can I fix this. Appreciate if you can give me some clue. Thanks.

```
PymntSuccessRate = 
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX(
            FILTER(
                GROUPBY(
                    Payment_Methods, 
                    Payment_Methods[timestamp], Payment_Methods[weekDay], Payment_Methods[Hour] 
                ),
                Payment_Methods[eventType] = "Success"
            ), 
            SUM( Payment_Methods[addPymntCardInstance] )
        ), 
        SUMX(
            GROUPBY(
                Payment_Methods, 
                Payment_Methods[timestamp], Payment_Methods[weekDay], Payment_Methods[Hour]
            ), 
            SUM( Payment_Methods[addPymntCardInstance] )
        )
    )
```

| timestamp | weekDay | Hour | SuccessEvents | FailedEvents | SuccessRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-20 | Friday | 20 | 2 | 8 | 0.20 |
| 2023-01-20 | Friday | 19 | 121 | 111 | 0.52 |
| 2023-01-17 | Tuesday | 6 | 31 | 8 | 0.79 |
| 2023-01-17 | Tuesday | 5 | 19 | 14 | 0.57 |

Comment: try swtiching the filter and groupby order?

Comment: Like `FILTER` inside `GROUPBY`?

Comment: <code>
PymntSuccessRate = 
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX(
            GROUPBY(
                FILTER(
                    Payment_Methods,
                    Payment_Methods[eventType] = "Success"
                ), 
                Payment_Methods[timestamp], Payment_Methods[weekDay], Payment_Methods[Hour] 
            ),
            SUM( Payment_Methods[addPymntCardInstance] )
        ), 
       ....
    )
</code>
All values now are 100%

Comment: you are mis-using GROUPBY function, it's intended for different purposes. Use SUMMARAIZE function instead.

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample you don't need to use SUMX and GROUPBY (visual will do the grouping), this should be enough (used as a measure, NOT a calculated column):

```
PymntSuccessRate =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Payment_Methods[addPymntCardInstance] ),
        Payment_Methods[eventType] = "Success"
    ),
    SUM ( Payment_Methods[addPymntCardInstance] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Stachu but that expression is giving me the average Rate of all observations meeting that condition (aka successRate) but I am looking at successRate at every timestamp, weekDay, and Hour. So, I should have a different value of successRate every day, hour. As indicated in the example provided. Thanks in advanced. And I agree the visual is doing the grouping of all addPymntCardInstance.

Comment: can you include sample values for PymntSuccessRate in the table you provided? The way I understand it, and in the context of the table you included, I see it as PymntSuccessRate = SuccessRate. If you would use matrix visual and collapsed [hour] the rate would be (2+ 121)/(2+8+121+111), so it will give different value at daily granularity, assuming you used the syntax as a measure, and not calculated column (then it's always gonna be constant, you cannot calculate columns dynamically)